# "User is not Defined" trouble filtering and rendering search results with React.Js/Material-Ui

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a search bar that filters through an array of users that are placed in a grid using Material-Ui styling. I have tried multiple times to map through and display the users but I am unable to render the page with the users displayed in a grid.

I keep getting an error saying "User is not Defined"

Here is the **UserList.js** code

```js
// implemented a class based component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './UserList.css'
// we will be using this for our cards
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import * as contentful from 'contentful';

class UserList extends Component {
  // state object contains two properties
    state = {
      users: [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mary Ann",
                "socialmedia": "Instagram",
                "following": "401k"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jessica P",
                "socialmedia": "Instagram",
                "following": "600k"
              }
            ],
      searchString: ''
    }

  constructor() {
    // super is the parent consturctor
    super()
    // we are making sure the list is loaded at the beginning of the lifecycle
    this.getUsers()
  }
// here we are implementing that method after we retreived it above
 getUsers = () => {
   // client.getEntries
   ({
     // what data are we returning
     content_type: 'user',
     // we use query because we will have a search filter activated
     // with this we will also need to make sure whent he user searches, the search barupdates accordingly
     query: this.state.searchString
   })
   // returns a promise
   // once there is a response, we use that callback function to make sure we ae setting the state again
   .then((response) => {
     this.setState({users: response.elements})
   })
   // in case there is an error we want to catch it
   .catch((error) => {
     console.log("Error occured while fetching data")
     console.log(error)
   })
 }
 // we are passing an event as a parameter
onSearchInputChange = (event) => {
  // if the value entered by the user in the textfield, make sure the state is updated
  if (event.target.value) {
    this.setState({searchString: event.target.value})
    // if that is not the case,we set the state to an empty string
  } else {
     this.setState({searchString: ''})
  }
  // we are making sure so the query is executed again and we are making sure only the users are returned, matching to our search stirng
  this.getUsers()
}
// The View
// now we are making sure it is rendered in the browser
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      {this.state.users ? (
           <div>
              <TextField style={{padding: 24}}
                id="searchInput"
                placeholder="Search for Influencers"
                margin="normal"
                onChange = {this.onSearchInputChange} />
        <Grid container spacing={24} style={{padding: 24}}>
        { this.state.users.map(currentUser => (
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                    <User user={currentUser} />
                                </Grid>
                            ))}
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
                ) : "No courses found" }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Here is the User.js Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia '
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/button';

const User = (props) => {
     return (
      <div>
         <h1 className='profile'> #HASHTAG HOUND </h1>
         {this.state.users.map((element, index) => {
           return  <div>
           <h1 className='profile'>{element.name}</h1>
           <h2 className='profile'>{element.socialmedia}</h2>
            <h2 className='profile'>{element.following}</h2>
           </div>
         })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Seems like you are not importing the `User` component inside UserList file. Fix it by importing it: `import User from './User';` (set it to the correct path)

Comment: FYI: you should call the `this.getUsers()` in `componentDidMount`, NOT in the `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is the `User` Component is not being imported inside the UserList.js file. So simply import it: `import User from './User';` (set it to the correct path).

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Click here to watch the => **[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qwmv7y)**

You were trying to get users data from UsersList file which is not possible by importing that file, you need to create another file where you put the data and use the data in both the files by exporting the data from the file and just import the **const user** from that file usersListData.jsx as shown on the working demo and apply map on that const.